# Redirect website domain (including all pages) to external URL after Popup message (few seconds)

Tags: functions, themes, redirect, wp-redirect

I am new to wordpress and I have made custom code as below. Where I can place this custom code in wordpress. I want to redirect the website domain and all pages but wanted to display popup message for few seconds (3 to 5) and automatically redirect to any external URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function Redirect() 
    {  
        window.location="https://example.com"; 
    } 
     $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
        setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);  
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Beaumondevillas are part of Natural Retreats</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>We are redirecting the Natural Retreats Palm Spring Page</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Where" somewhat depends on the theme you're using. Here's couple examples,

1. If you have a custom made theme, then you can put the code in any appropriate place. For example `header.php` (after `<head>`) or `footer.php`.
2. If you have child theme, then you can copy a suitable `template_part` file from the parent theme to the child dir and add the code to that file.
3. Add the code with a action/filter hook. For example `wp_footer` (*although the button might look a bit silly with this one*) or append it to `the_content`.
4. If you don't need to show the redirected domains content, you could create custom page template and page to which you first redirect all users with `template_redirect` (or `template_include`) to serve as a landing page. Then include your custom redirect modal on that page.